# Insert multiple row data same time sqlite with json ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to insert multiple row data same time to the sqlite database.But for example I have a value.I am getting that from my api.And in this value I have 2000 data.I am just adding 1 row and in that row I Can see 2000 data.

```
 for (NSDictionary *customerDictionary in customerArray) {
            Kart *kart = [Kart customerWithName:[customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adi"]];
            [_kartList addObject:kart];
        }
```

And I am using FMDB for the sqlite.

**EDIT**

I can add the one data to the sqlite db with that.But when I try to add another object to the database its adding all datas to the my database in one row.

Its just adding one row and correct data

```
[database executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KartDB (adi) VALUES (?)" withArgumentsInArray:kart.adi];
```

Its adding all data from kart.adi  and kart.adi2 in one row.

```
        [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KartDB (adi,adi2) VALUES (?,?)" withArgumentsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kart.adi,kart.adi2, nil]];
```

Can you give me a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

What's your `PRIMARY KEY` for the table you're trying to add the data into? Perhaps you're simply overriding inserts because the `PRIMARY KEY` isn't unique.

Would look something like this.

```
[database executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KartDB (primaryKey, adi,adi2) VALUES (?,?,?)" withArgumentsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:primaryKey, kart.adi,kart.adi2, nil]];
```

Also, if you're doing 2000 inserts at once, look into FMDB's `inTransaction` feature. Will make your updates much faster.

You could then call something like:

```
[dbManager.databaseQueue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {

 for (NSDictionary *customerDictionary in customerArray) {
        Kart *kart = [Kart customerWithName:[customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adi"]];

        [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KartDB (primaryKey, adi) VALUES (?,?)", primaryKey, kart.adi];

    }

}];
[dbManager.databaseQueue close];
```

Comment: what if i have multiple arrays like customerArray? how can i insert