# SQLite Insert Multiple rows from JSON object ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, fmdb

I am getting json data over http using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession) class

```
    NSString *url = @"http://10.0.0.25/Website/database.php";

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"String Output: %@",str);


    });
}];
[task resume];
```

i am getting the following sample output below:

{ 
      "client_id":"12",
      "finger_print_code":"",
      "national_id":"28811982"
   },
   { 
      "client_id":"32",
      "finger_print_code":"",
      "national_id":"293239323"
   }

i would like to get the above data from JSON string or object into my SQLite Database. Someone suggested [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), but i am not quite familiar with it.

```
  query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into clientInfo values(null, %d, %d, '%@')", [importedID intValue], [nationalID intValue], fingerPrintCode];
```

This is how to [insert multiple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database?rq=1), but i would like to learn how to insert data when its from JSON, and insert it at once or at the same time.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224093/insert-multiple-row-data-same-time-sqlite-with-json-ios?rq=1) is one of examples but it did not prove to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that sample data is actually a JSON array

```
[{ "client_id":"12", "finger_print_code":"", "national_id":"28811982" },
 { "client_id":"32", "finger_print_code":"", "national_id":"293239323" }]
```

and the version of sqlite you're using has the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension enabled, you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO clientInfo(client_id, finger_print_code, national_id)
SELECT json_extract(j.value, '$.client_id')
     , json_extract(j.value, '$.finger_print_code')
     , json_extract(j.value, '$.national_id')
FROM json_each(?) AS j;
```

where you bind the string holding the JSON array to the parameter in the prepared statement created from the above query. Adjust column names as needed (Since you didn't give a table definition I guessed).

Comment: Hi there, Where j is what exactly, the JSON array?? thanx

Comment: @bots_developer_fix It's just the alias used for the rows returned by `json_each()`. See the linked documentation for details. Or a basic sql tutorial if you've never seen `AS` or don't know what an alias is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. This is how i implemented it in Objective-c incase one might want to know how.In this scenario i used a custom database class to communicate with my SQLite Database.

```
        NSString *queryInsert;
    queryInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO clientInfo(clientID, nationalID, fingerPrintCode) SELECT json_extract(j.value, '$.client_id') , json_extract(j.value, '$.national_id') , json_extract(j.value, '$.finger_print_code')  FROM json_each('%@') AS j", my_json_array];
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:queryInsert];
```

Where my_json_array is exactly that the jsonArray of data i get from my server. I didnt know much about [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension, thank you for your assistance and for sharing that knowledge.